# ics download works on PC but not on android

Tags: php, android, apache2, codeigniter-4

I implemented a function to download ics calendar file from my site. And it works fine when clicking on the link from in chrome on my laptop. But when do the same on my samsung phone with android and chrome, it puts .html behind the filename.

So when downloading on my laptop, it downloads NF-Vakt.ics, but on my phone NF-Vakt.ics.html

**Update**: Im pretty sure this has to do with the setup on my apache2 webserver (running ubuntu), i'm able to open ics files from other servers(webhotel) with the same methods.

Here is my code. Using Codeigniter 4

function in the custom_helper

```
if ( ! function_exists('createIcs')) {
    function createIcs($title, $description, $start, $slutt, $adresse = '') {
        // Build the ics file
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/oslo
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Oslo:' . dateToCal($slutt) . '
UID:' . md5($title) . '
DTSTAMP:' . time() . '
LOCATION:' . addslashes($adresse) . '
DESCRIPTION:' . esc($description) . '
URL;VALUE=URI: 
SUMMARY:' . addslashes($title) . '
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Oslo:' . dateToCal($start) . '
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
        header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: multipart; filename=NF-Vakt.ics');
        echo $ical;

    }
}
```

The controller

```
 public function icsCal($skiftID){
        $vakter = new VakterModel();
        $skifter = new SkiftModel();
        $sted = new StedModel();
        $kunde = new KunderModel();
        $type = new TypeModel();

        // $request = service('request');
        // $postData = $request->getGet();

        //Henter skiftinformasjon
        $data['skift'] = $skifter->where('skift_id', $skiftID)->first();

        //henter vaktinformasjon
        $data['vakt'] = $vakter->where('vakt_id', $data['skift']['vakt_id'])->first();

        //henter sted info
        $data['sted'] = $sted->where('sted_id', $data['vakt']['sted_id'])->first();
        
        //henter type info
        $data['type'] = $type->where('type_id', $data['vakt']['type_id'])->first();
        
        //henter stkudneed info
        $data['kunde'] = $kunde->where('kunde_id', $data['vakt']['kunde_id'])->first();

        return view('/vakter/sendcal', $data);

    }
```

The route

```
$routes->get("/vakter/icsCal/(:num)", "VaktController::icsCal/$1", ['filter' => 'auth']);
```

and the view

```
<?php
helper("custom"); // loading helper
$description = $vakt['oppdrag']." - ". $type['type']."\\n"."\\nOppmøte: ".$sted['oppmote']." ".$sted['oppmote_tid']." timer før vaktstart. \\nKunde: ".$kunde['firma']."\\n\\n".ltrim($vakt['info']);
if ($kunde['adresse']) {
    $adresse = $kunde['adresse'].",".$kunde['postnr']." ".$kunde['sted'];
} else {
    $adresse = "";
}
createIcs($vakt['oppdrag'], esc($description), $skift['start'], $skift['slutt'], $adresse);
?>
```

and it calls this view using this link

```
<span class="float-end"><a href="/vakter/icsCal/<?=$s['skift_id'];?>"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i></a></span></div>
```

Hav tried to add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html .htm .ics"
to my apache2.conf but that didn't help either. And have not found any similar problems on google either.

Comment: Why is your content disposition multipart? Can you change it to `attachment`?

Comment: Well.. It was just an attemt to try something. But same result with attachement.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's happening to me too